# reset stack navigation when move from drawer navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a drawer navigation like that

```
const DrawerNavigatorRoutes = (props) => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="homeScreenStack"
        component={homeScreenStack}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={profileScreenStack}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};
```

When I click `homeScreenStack` the stack navigation is like that

```
const homeScreenStack = ({ navigation }) => {
return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Dashboard">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Dashboard"
        component={Dashboard}
       />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="screen2"
        component={screen2}
       />
      ....
   </Stack.Navigator>
);
```

};

I also have some tab navigation in `homeScreenStack` So I want that when ever I click on `homeScreenStack` from drawer navigation `Dashboard` screen will open But in current scenario it didn't reset the stack. I am using react navigation 5

Comment: You can navigate to the specific screen inside of the navigator. That should do it

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading what you're asking correctly, you should be able to use the unmountOnBlur and set that to true on your drawer navigator to reset your stack. Then when you navigate back to your drawer navigator it will reset your stack navigator. So your code would look like:

```
 const DrawerNavigatorRoutes = (props) => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
     unmountOnBlur: true,
    >
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="homeScreenStack"
        component={homeScreenStack}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={profileScreenStack}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks @ms217, I was looking for the same and this worked.!